# Splitting list and iterating in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, artificial-intelligence

Im trying to do something which seems to be really simple but i cant get my head around. I want to split a list in prolog from given predicates and iterate over the objects.
Example:

```
object_properties(jackass, [comedy, -australian]).
object_properties(the_godfather, [drama, crime, -character_batman]).
```

How can i iterate over the lists and print it to the screen? More specificaly i need to ask the user if the object  has the property. If they say yes move on to the next item in the list, if they say no move on to the next object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this could help you to start

```
object_properties :-
    object_properties(O, Ps),
    query_user_loop(O, Ps).

query_user_loop(_, []).
query_user_loop(O, [P|Ps]) :-
    write([object, O, has, P, ?]),
    read(Answer),
    (   Answer == yes
    ->  query_user_loop(O, Ps)
    ).

object_properties(jackass, [comedy, -australian]).
object_properties(the_godfather, [drama, crime, -character_batman]).
```

this does for simple interaction (please note the dot after each answer):

```
9 ?- object_properties.
[object,jackass,has,comedy,?]yes.
[object,jackass,has,-australian,?]no.
[object,the_godfather,has,drama,?]yes.
[object,the_godfather,has,crime,?]yes.
[object,the_godfather,has,-character_batman,?]yes.
true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This is exactly what i was confused about.